# Value is always true, even if false

Tags: c#, configuration

```
        /*****For Local setup****/
        var isLocal = _configuration.GetValue<bool>("IsLocalEvn");
        if (isLocal)
            return isLocal;
```

This is always returning true even if the value in appsettings is false

From appsettings.json

```
"IsLocalEvn": "false",
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the *boolean* type inside the JSON file.

```
"IsLocalEvn": false,
```

In your case, you are using a *string* value which is *interpreted* as `true` when it's converted to a `boolean`.